# Move row up or down in bootstraptable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I'm using [Bootstrap-Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) in a project and I'd like to move rows up or down.

I have these action events :

```
window.actionEvents = {
'click .up': function (e, value, row, index) {
var thisrow = $(this).parents("tr:first"),
thisrow.prev().data('index', rowindex);
},
'click .down': function (e, value, row, index) {
var thisrow = $(this).parents("tr:first");
thisrow.insertAfter(thisrow.next());
},
}
```

It moves rows on screen but it doesn't work really well as row index haven't changed...

So I tried to change  the row `.data('index')` but it doesn't work...

Has someone succeeded in moving row ?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle???

Comment: Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dfpo899p/ if you move rows by clicking + or - and press button you can see that data remains the same and it causes issues if i add a delete button by example ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is something :

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/dfpo899p/1/

**Js** :

```
window.actionEvents = {
    'click .up': function (e, value, row, index) {
        var source = JSON.stringify($('#table').bootstrapTable('getData')[index]);
        var target = JSON.stringify($('#table').bootstrapTable('getData')[index - 1]);
        $('#table').bootstrapTable('updateRow', {'index':index - 1, 'row': JSON.parse(source)});
        $('#table').bootstrapTable('updateRow', {'index':index, 'row': JSON.parse(target)});
        },
    'click .down': function (e, value, row, index) {
        var source = JSON.stringify($('#table').bootstrapTable('getData')[index]);
        var target = JSON.stringify($('#table').bootstrapTable('getData')[index + 1]);
        $('#table').bootstrapTable('updateRow', {'index':index + 1, 'row': JSON.parse(source)});
        $('#table').bootstrapTable('updateRow', {'index':index, 'row': JSON.parse(target)});
        }
}
```